# Is there a way to have PHPUnit determine code coverage for @method declarations?

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit, code-coverage

I have a number of methods being declared in a class with the standard phpdoc @method syntax, for example:

```
/**
 * @method string magicMethod(int $arg1, array $arg2) Method description.
 */
class ... { }
```

Is it possible to configure PHPUnit to check against these comments when determining method-level code coverage?  Currently, my coverage is at 100%, even though I've only touched about 10% of these magic methods so far.

Answer (score 3):

Code coverage can only be calculated based on existing code, not on "virtual" methods.

To get a more realistic statistic, you should reduce the amount of coverage that gets generated unintentionally. PHPUnit does generate coverage for every line of code that gets executed when using the default configuration - which is bad, because if you unintentionally run along lines that do not get tested with an assertion, the coverage does not tell you anything at all (apart from the fact that no error occurred there).

When you have a look at the [code coverage chapter](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/code-coverage-analysis.html) in the manual, you see that you can specify which methods are tested with a test, and only those methods are generating coverage statistics (section "Specifying covered methods").

The method I prefer is to set the option `mapTestClassNameToCoveredClassName="true"` in [the phpunit.xml file](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/appendixes.configuration.html), and add all classes to be tested to the whitelist. That way, the coverage will automatically be restricted to only the class that has the same name (less the suffix "Test") as the test class. So if you have a test "MyGreatModelTest", it will only create coverage in any method of the "MyGreatModel" class, and not anywhere else.

And if you add the whole directory with your code to the whitelist, you will also catch all files that did generate 0 % coverage and thus were not included in the statistics so far.

Beware: These settings might hurt your feelings, but they will give you a more realistic picture of which lines of code get really run during a test, and which are only passed as a side effect.

Comment: This does not really answer my question regarding getting PHPUnit to recognize magic methods declared via the .@method doc.  Defining .@cover clauses for magic methods will simply return a failure from phpdoc:

PHP_CodeCoverage_Exception: Trying to .@cover not existing method

Comment: No, there is no way to mark these as covered, because they are no real code (comments are not part of code coverage detection). My suggestion was to reduce all coverage noise from calls that do not explicitly test that part of the code, to allow seeing which parts are to be tested more intensely.

Comment: mapTestClassNameToCoveredClassName not longer works since php-code-coverage v2

Answer (score 2):

PHPUnit uses its own annotations applied to your TestCase class. It doesn't parse annotations on tested class.

To restrict the source code lines used during code coverage analysis for a specific test, you have to use the [@covers](https://phpunit.de/manual/6.0/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.covers) annotation.

In case of using magic methods in the tested class:

```php
/**
 * @covers My\Class::__call
 */
public function testMyMagicMethod()
{
     $this->assertSomething($this->subject->magicMethod());
}
```

As [__call()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) is the real method called in you tested class, the covered
source code lines should be in it.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is super old, but the answer you're looking for is to mock the __call method.

```
$this->clientMock->expects(static::at(1))
        ->method('__call')
        ->with('get', [RedisAdapter::CONNECTION_TEST])
        ->will(static::returnValue(RedisAdapter::CONNECTION_TEST_VALUE));
```